# Join strings along axis

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array of strings, like this:

```
import numpy as np
print('numpy version:', np.__version__)

a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
stra = a.astype(np.dtype(str))

print(stra)
```

output:

```
numpy version: 1.15.2
[['0' '1' '2' '3' '4']
 ['5' '6' '7' '8' '9']
 ['10' '11' '12' '13' '14']
 ['15' '16' '17' '18' '19']
 ['20' '21' '22' '23' '24']]
```

I want to work along a given axis, choose some elements, and join those strings.  First I tried this:

```
print(np.apply_along_axis('|'.join, 1, stra.take([2, 3], 1)))
```

But the longer resulting strings get truncated to match the shortest:

```
['2|3' '7|8' '12|' '17|' '22|']
```

I can of course write my own loop to get the output I want, but it's somewhat unsatisfying to do this when the one-liner so nearly works.

```
def join_along_axis(array, indices, axis):        
    if array.ndim == 1:
        return np.array('|'.join(array.take(indices)))

    joined = []        
    # Move axis of interest to end and flatten others to make the loop easy.
    work_arr = np.rollaxis(array, axis, -1)
    shape = work_arr.shape
    new_shape = (np.product(work_arr.shape[:-1]), work_arr.shape[-1])
    work_arr = work_arr.reshape(new_shape)

    for arr in work_arr:
        joined.append('|'.join(arr.take(indices)))

    return np.array(joined).reshape(shape[:-1])

print(join_along_axis(stra, [2, 3], 1))
```

output:

```
['2|3' '7|8' '12|13' '17|18' '22|23']
```

Is there a slicker way to do this than my `join_along_axis` function?

**Update for clarity:**  I need this to be general enough to work on an array with arbitrary number of dimensions and along any chosen axis.

Comment: My guess is that `apply_along` is doing a test calc on the first row, and using that to set the result dtype. Rows that produce longer strings get truncated.  Look at the `apply_along` code.  After all the setup, it iterates, calling the 1d function once for each 'row'. It may make the task simpler, if it works, but won't be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I first tried to do it your way using `apply_along_axis` but I found that it might be trickier, [apparently](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8352) NP isn't well defined for coping with strings.

So how about list comprehension?

```
a =a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
stra = a.astype(np.dtype(str))
only23 = zip(stra[:,2],stra[:,3])
only23
```

output:

> [('2', '3'), ('7', '8'), ('12', '13'), ('17', '18'), ('22', '23')]

now lets do the comprehension:

```
[x[0] +'|'+x[1] for x in only23]
```

output:

> ['2|3', '7|8', '12|13', '17|18', '22|23']

And you can actually make it be a one-liner, I just don't think it will be that readable

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the GitHub issue. It's a useful conversion to read.  I should have been clearer in my OP that the array could have more dimensions (or just one, in which case my existing `join_along_axis` will break!)  If there are more dimensions, then I think the reshaping I have done in my function will still be necessary with the list comprehension approach.  I'll update the OP.

Answer (score 1):

From the GitHub conversation linked by @theshopen, it seems I can use a `lambda` to specify the string size I want.  So this works:

```
lens = np.vectorize(len)
indices = [2, 3]
axis = 1

new_len = lens(stra.take(indices, axis)).sum(1).max() + len(indices) - 1
new_type = '{}{}'.format(stra.dtype.char, new_len)

print(np.apply_along_axis(
    lambda x: np.array('|'.join(x), new_type),
    axis, stra.take(indices, axis)))
```

Comment: So how does the speed compare?

Comment: @hpaulj, actually my original function is faster.  Even if I take the calculation of `new_len` and `new_type` outside of the `timeit` loop, this method still takes nearly twice as long.  I think my original function also wins on readability so perhaps I will stick with it!